# Loading & Connecting Facebook Pixel Conversions Data

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

I am trying to load the Facebook Pixel Conversions level data from the Marketing/Insights API but not able to do it at the level I want or even properly

1. I have various pixels created in the form of events eg: Leads, Registrations etc and need to track them

After reading the documentation for [Ads Pixels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/) and it's [stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats/) - I was able to load some basic fields for now - but still not able to pull the s

GET API Query : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_/adspixels?fields=name,id,creation_time,last_fired_time

This gives me all the correct Ads Pixel details but how do I pull all the stats for this in the form of Events, their occurrences etc - will I be using more query parameters in this URL or a new URL - tried multiple iterations but was not able to get anything to work for now.

Tried this API Query as per documentation -: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9//stats - but does not work even with fields added etc

2. Another issue I had was I am not at all able to test my queries with Graph API explorer - it keeps telling me that "Timeout issue" or "some other errors" when I am trying to use the app etc there. Do I need to publish and approve the app before hitting FB Ads data via the API Explorer?

All your suggestions and feedback will be highly appreciated here

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for some things related and encoutered your thread.. I will report my findings .. maybe you already know this, but here it goes.

As far as querying with Graph API explorer.. it doesn't seem to work with Marketing API. You need to create your own app, and enable market api, in order to get the necessary token. 
I am following the instructions on the link you provided: [stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats/)

Second.. to get the stats I am using
 *graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{pixel-id}/stats?aggregation=pixel_fire*
The aggregation is  necessary to get results. I can get the "Page View" event listed that I am tracking on a website.

I was able to compare these results, with the ones showed to me on the events manager page of the pixel.

Hope this helps